# Wordpress Elementor Slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, elementor

the slider is shown below and the content corresponding to the slider is shown on top. When you change the slider, the content on top changes. Please help with a solution.

[image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nz8t.jpg)

I tried to use a tab or plugin on the slider but all attempts failed.